# Counting number of seating arrangements with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Here is the question:

A group of 10 people are assigned to sit in a row of 10 seats. Let's call them A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, and J.

If A needs to sit somewhere to the left of C (but not necessarily immediately next to C), and also somewhere to the right of G (but not necessarily immediately next to G), how many ways can we assign the 10 people to their seats?

This is my attempt at answering the question, which I believe to be incorrect:

The relative ordering we want is G, A, C. First, we need to figure out how many ways we can arrange these 3 together. Treating these 3 people as 1 contiguous group, the problem simplifies to 8 people (7 others plus G, A, and C as 1), of which we need to choose 3 seats. This gives $P(8,3)=\frac{8!}{5!}=336$. Now there are 7 other people to arrange, which is given by $7!=5040$. Thus, the total number of possible assignments is $P(8,3)\cdot 7!=336\cdot 5040=1693440$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any given ordering of the 10 people 5 more can be obtained by permutations of A,C,G but we want them to have a fixed order which is G,A,C so we will divide the total permutations possible by 3!.

Hence the answer is $$\frac{10!}{3!}$$

EDIT:

To make it more simple consider this. Each arrangement which follows the given condition can generate 3! arrangement by permutations of A,C,G. Therefore

$$N (3!)=10!$$

Comment: neat answer! @Aarush Saharan